# Trouble extracting values from a string in postgres

Tags: postgresql, substring, postgresql-9.6

I have a string `X-99-XX-999` in postgres 9.6. I'm looking to extract `XX`. The `XX` is always between the second and the third hyphen. Can anyone please help?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Use the function `split_part()`

```
select split_part('X-99-XX-999', '-', 3)

 split_part 
------------
 XX
(1 row)
```

From [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

> split_part(string text, delimiter text, field int)
>
> Split string on delimiter and return the given field (counting from one)